# Copy a pixel color (ImageMagick)

Tags: imagemagick

How can I specify a color from an given pixel to -fill ?

```
convert -gravity center -background rgb\(222,97,56\) -fill "#%[hex:u.p{10,10}/2]" -size 120x60 -pointsize 42 label:Test -depth 8 out.png
```

Error : convert: unable to open image '#%[hex:u.p{10,10}/2]': No such file or directory

```
-format '%[hex:p{10,10}/2]\n' info:
```

returns "6F311C" and -fill "#6F311C" works though.

Comment: I see what's wrong. You are trying to use the colour of pixel at (10,10) when there isn't any image loaded or created yet.

Comment: No, it works with (10,10). The issues are `convert` and `hex`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me in Imagemagick 7. Add the # sign to your hex command.

```
magick -size 120x60 -background "rgb(222,97,56)" -depth 8 -fill "#%[hex:u.p{10,10}/2]" -pointsize 42 -gravity center label:Test -depth 8 out.png
```

[image]

*Note that Imagemagick 7 was implemented to add such in-line computations that were not available in Imagemagick 6.*

Comment: Using `magick` instead of `convert` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Try this if you want to use `label:` rather than `-annotate`:

```
magick -gravity center -size 100x100 xc:yellow  \
   -fill black -draw "rectangle 10,10 100,100" \
   -fill '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' -background magenta -size 100x80 -pointsize 42 label:"Label" -append result.png
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

I think you want this:

```
magick -gravity center -size 100x100 xc:yellow  \
    -fill black -draw "rectangle 10,10 100,100" \
    -fill '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' -annotate 0 "text" result.png
```

[image]

The first 2 lines create a yellow canvas with a black rectangle overlaying the bottom-right part leaving the top-left pixel yellow. The fill colour is then taken from pixel (0,0) and used for the text annotation.

Comment: No, I really want a label, not an annotation (to control font and size). Why is -fill complaining about the %[] expression in my command, when it works in your example ? Tried adding a rectangle like you (so p{10,10} has something to pick from, maybe?), but same error message.

Comment: Maybe you have v6 **ImageMagick**. I am using v7.

Comment: I understood your question was about how to set the fill colour from a specific pixel position. Whether you subsequently use that fill colour for an annotaion or a label or drawing a circle shouldn't make any difference - I would have thought.

Comment: ImageMagick 7.0.10-27 Q16 x86_64. I agree, once the pixel color is properly picked, it shouldn't matter what I use it for. -fill is the one that disagrees (error message).

Comment: I have updated it to use `label:` - please have another look.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. That gives me what I want, with -crop +100+0. No need for a rectangle. Also it reveals the actual issue with my original command : you can't do (apparently) hex/2 in an fx expression, you can do pixel/2 !

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issue in different OS platforms in Imagemagick, you should use double quotes.

The following should return the hex value for blue:

```
magick xc:red xc:blue xc:green1 +append -depth 8 -format "%[hex:u.p{1,0}]" info:

0000FFF
```

If you really want to do division, then

```
magick xc:red xc:blue xc:green1 +append -depth 8 -format "%[hex:u.p{1,0}/2]" info:

000080
```

So to put that into a label,

```
# create image
magick xc:red xc:blue xc:green1 +append rgb.png

# put color into label
magick rgb.png -set label "%[hex:u.p{1,0}/2]" rgb.png

# check label
magick rgb.png -format "%l" info:

000080
```

Comment: I don't want to know/print the value of the "%[]" expression, I want to *use it as argument to -fill* to set the color of the text. Same error with double quotes (thanks for the hint).